# Insert shape with Range.top value as its top value, it will trigger an alignment problem

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

When inserting a shape in a workbook, try to get Range.top value and assign it as Shape's top value, it cannot align with the Range's top border due to the implementation algorithm not accurate.
Here is the repro gist:
https://gist.github.com/gingerjia/42b043743cfb4ad45e0df4c5e478172e

And it can repro on some workbook, not all workbook can repro the issue:
[image]

Comment: Please post your code, as well as the error you are receiving. Also, office-js and office-scripts are two separate technologies/scripting language.

Comment: for the workbook that you can repro this issue, have you changed the row height for that workbook?

Comment: Yes, the selected range to insert shape is under ranges that has been modified the row height by wrap text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Ginger, This is a known issue.

The root cause is the computational accuracy, the current algorithm works in the default normal height of the workbook, but when the workbook row height is changed (in your case, some rows are large) might cause this misalignment issue for `range.top`.

So our team has figure out the solution, the code has been checked in, and it is on the way to roll out. you should be able to get the right result pretty soon.